# how to show pincodes in sorted order on blur in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am using `react-hook-form`.I have pincode `textarea` in which user can enter `pincodes`,Now I want to validate my value on `blur` mean pincode should be `6`digit and present in sorted order.

`onblur` event not work properly ?
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-v24jk

```
<TextField
        inputRef={register}
        label={"pincode"}
        variant="outlined"
        placeholder={"dd"}
        multiline={true}
        rows="4"
        rowsMax="12"
        name={"pincode"}
        onBlur={v => {
          console.log(v);
          function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
            return self.indexOf(value) === index && value.trim().length === 6;
          }

          if (v) {
            let codes = v.split(",");
            let newCodes = codes.filter(onlyUnique);
            return newCodes.sort().join(",");
          }
          return "";
        }}
      />
```

react hook form API
https://react-hook-form.com/api

Answer (score 0):

```
onBlur={v => {...}
```

Your `v` variable represents the event object for the onBlur event. You can get the value from the `textarea` from `v.target.value`. `v.target.value.split(",")` should work, though you may end up with an empty string in your array if there's only one PIN entered.